# php array does not unset

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to unset my shoppingkart array

```
 if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
        $delete=$_GET['delete'];
        if($_GET['delete']=="all"){
            unset($_SESSION['shoppingkart']);
        }
         else{
            $key=array_search($delete, $_SESSION['shoppingkart']);
            unset($_SESSION['shoppingkart'][$key]);
        }
    }
```

the second part deletes only one value of the array. And it works.
But the first part, deleting the entire array does not. it only deletes the first value.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is entering the "all" portion?  I'd put either an echo or die() in there to make sure it is reaching the code inside that `if` statement (perhaps it is All instead of all and causing case issues?).

Comment: Dear unset will delete all array and there is possibility that code does not reach at unset($array).. first be clear that unset function excute or not??

Comment: Can you get a `var_dump($_SESSION['shoppingkart'])` (in the if-conditional before the `unset($_SESSION['shoppingkart']);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of reasons why it might be doing that ... Either you believe it has ran the first (unset all) part of the code, when in-fact it is running the second part. Or, assuming you are using `print_r($_SESSION)` to see what is still set, make sure you use it AFTER running the code ...

What you could try, to see what part of the code is actually being ran, and in an `echo 'First statement ran'` and `echo 'Second statement ran'` in the relevent parts of the code ...

I say this, because the `unset($_SESSION['shoppingkart']);` looks correct